# Enumerate Active Directory group members (nested) including Domain Users (Primary Group)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Currently I use the GetMembers-method of the groupprincipal-class (.NET 3.5) (with **true**) to enumerate all members of a group (incl. nested groups).

If in a subgroup the primary domain group (Domain-Users) is member, I cannot enumerate alle the members correctly. The mentioned method doesn't enumerate the Domain-Users group.

Any ideas to avoid this problem? I need a fast algorithm. So enumerating every group/subgroup seperate isn't a good solution.

Comment: have you tried .GetGroups() from the GroupPrincipal object?

Comment: GetGroups()-method of the relevant GroupPrincipal returns the groups of which this is a direct member. Not the members of the relevant GroupPrincipal itself.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm struggling with it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am using System.DirectoryServices to send LDAP queries.

It is fast; I use it to query ~100k users and it takes ~20-30 seconds.
(on an external domain though, it would be even faster if I was on local domain)

Here's how I do it:

```
DirectoryEntry DE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=ou_to_search_recursively", user, password);
using (DirectorySearcher DSE = new DirectorySearcher(DE))
{
    DSE.PageSize = 1000;
    //get only users
    DSE.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
    //search recursively
    DSE.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    //load the properties that you want
    DSE.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
    DSE.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
    DSE.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
    DSE.PropertiesToLoad.Add("other_attribute_you_might_want");

    foreach (SearchResult u in DSE.FindAll())
    {
        //check if property exists
        if (u.Properties.Contains("distinguishedName")) {
            // access property: 
            string dn = u.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: I want to enumerate members of a GROUP.